# Implementations of interfaces - Java

Tags: java, interface, sortedmap

This is probably a very basic question but I'm genuinely confused...
I would like to know how to implement `String get(Integer k)` from an interface into another class's method.

```
public interface SimpleSortedMap {

    // Map ADT methods:
    // Returns the number of entries in the map
    int size();

    // Is the map empty or not
    boolean isEmpty();

    // Returns the value associated with key k, if such an entry
    // exists; otherwise returns null
    String get(Integer k);

    // If there is no entry with key equal to k, then adds entry
    // (k,v) and returns null; else replaces with v the existing
    // value and returns the old value.
    String put(Integer k, String v);

    // Removes the entry with key equal to k and returns its value 
    // If no such entry exists, then returns null
    String remove(Integer k);

    // Returns an iterable collection containing all the keys
    // stored in the map
    Iterable<Integer> keySet();

}
```

The Class where I implemented this interface is here

```
public class BstSimpleSortedMap implements SimpleSortedMap {

    private String get(Integer k, MySimpleEntry subtreeRoot) {
        // base case: empty subtree
        if (subtreeRoot == null) {
            // k isn't in this subtree
            return null;
        }

        // base case: k matches the key in the current entry
        if (k.compareTo(subtreeRoot.getKey()) == 0) {
            // return the value
            return null;
        } // recursive case: k < the current entry
        else if (k.compareTo(subtreeRoot.getKey()) < 0) {
            // return the result of recursing to the left
            return null;
        } // recursive case: k > the current entry
        else {
            // return the result of recursing to the right
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

this isn't the full code but I would like to know how to use the ADT methods in public interface SimpleSortedMap and recall them in BSTSimpleSortedMap. example, I want to write code which is equivalent to return `String get(Integer k)` on line 11 of BSTSimpleSortedMap

Comment: As I said below, your CLASS needs to implement the INTERFACE.  The example code you've shown doesn't.  The main part, however, is you need to figure out how to implement a BST in your class.  Here's an example: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/BST.java.html.  Note in particular the "private" members, like `private Node root`.  These are the "implementation details" the class needs to do its work.  Note, too, there's a `public Value get(Key key)` and a `private Value get(Node x, Key key)`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

The signature in your class implementation must match that of the interface.  Furthermore, you must implement ALL the methods in the interface:

```
public class BstSimpleSortedMap implements SimpleSortedMap {

  String get(Integer k) { ... }

  int size() { ... }

  boolean isEmpty() { ... }

  ...
}
```

The hard part is actually implementing your Binary Search Tree (BST).

Your "get()" simply returns the "i'th" element in the tree.

Q: Can you show us any of that code?